# how can i get and pass variables in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have following in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^MyPage page.php?type=mypage [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^MyPhotos page.php?type=photos [NC, L]
```

it is working fine but if i pass any variable to my url i.e

```
http://www.mydomain.com/MyPage?id=1
```

than i am unable to fetch that id via `$_GET['id'];`
how can i do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Query String Append](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString):

```
RewriteRule ^MyPhotos page.php?type=photos [NC, L, QSA]
```